# Ubuntu 14.04 Wallpaper not scaling right after login

Tags: ati, login, desktop-background

Whenever I login, my middle and top monitor always have their wallpaper out of scale and it's quite annoying. I have an AMD Radeon HD6870 with the latest AMD proprietary drivers (14.6?). I always need to switch wallpapers and switch back to make it scale correctly.

[Screenshot](https://i.stack.imgur.com/EYnCj.jpg)

Any ideas?

Thanks.